# Jquery to slide on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple slider that works on click. How can I automate it so it runs automatically yet keeping the click function as it is?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentPosition = 0;
    var slideHeight = 360;
    var slides = $('.main-item');
    var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
    var tracker = 0;
    $('.slider-height').css('height', slideHeight * numberOfSlides);
    $('.slide-option li a').click(function() {
        tracker = $('.slide-option li a').index($(this));
        $('.slide-option li a').removeClass('current-item');
        $(this).addClass('current-item');
        //alert(tracker);
        $('.slider-height').animate({
            'top': slideHeight * (-tracker)
        });
        return false;
        //alert(tracker);
    });
});​
```

Comment: You want it to run continuously, or just once when the page loads? If it were to run continuously, how would the click still work?

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger your click after you've bound the click event:

```
$('.slide-option li a').trigger('click');
```